# Starting Program with Admin Rights in C#

Tags: c#, java, admin, admin-rights, administrative

as I recently found out, it's hard to start a Java process with administrative rights from code, so I decided to make a separate startup or calling program, written in C#. The C# program has the rights to run as an administrator, but how can I call the jar to run as one, though?
The program it's calling requires admin rights to set and retrieve values from the registry, which are its settings, and as I can't start the program as an admin in Java, I need to do so in C# (I chose C# over VB, because I used to code in VB, but don't like the syntax anymore). This is how far I've gotten so far, but I still get an error output in the console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Universal Android Toolkit Bootup...";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        try
        {
            Process pr = new Process();
            String uat = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/com.m4gkbeatz.Java.AndroidToolkit.jar";

            pr.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar " + uat;
            pr.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
            pr.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pr.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
            pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pr.StartInfo.UserName = "admin";
            pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            StreamReader str;
            pr.Start();
            str = pr.StandardOutput;

            while (!pr.HasExited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error while attempting to execute Universal Android Toolkit");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            error = ex.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again.\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();
            ErrorMenu();
        }
    }
```

Edit: This is the console's output:
[image: Console Error Output]

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error indicates "bad username/password"...
you're setting `pr.StartInfo.UserName` but not `pr.StartInfo.Password`

Comment: But it's the administrator account. It doesn't have a password. Thats's what's bugging me. Any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: Yes I did. But then Java gets started with minimal rights, which isn't what I wanted.